# Condition for Update vs insert

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I have a table tblCosts which i display on an msaccess front end which enables users to add new entries as well as update existing ones. The table is structured as below.

```
ExpenseType       Month     Year     Cost 
Hardware          June      2017     $500 
Software          July      2017     $300 
Hardware          Sept      2017     $150
```

I have an update and insert queries which work fine when run manually.
However I am having trouble differentiating the condition when to fire the query on the form. For example, if the record exists in the table, it should run the update query, if record does not exist, it should run the insert query.

For example if someone puts in 
- Hardware         Sept    2017    $120 
 it should update the 3rd entry from 150 to 120 but if someone puts in 
- Furniture         Sept    2017    $350 
 it should recognize that Furniture is not part of the DB and run the insert query. 
 I have the update and insert queries but need help in identifying the condition when to run them.

The Update query I'm using is:

```
Update tblCosts 
set tblCosts.Cost=[Forms]![frmCost]![txtCost] 
where tblCosts.ExpenseType = [Forms]![frmCost]![txtExpType] 
and tblCosts.Month = [Forms]![frmCost]![txtMonth] 
and tblCosts.Year = [Forms]![frmCost]![txtYear]
```

The Insert query I'm using is:

```
Insert into tblCosts (ExpenseType , Month, Year, Cost) 
Select [Forms]![frmCost]![txtExpType] as Exp1, 
[Forms]![frmCost]![txtMonth] as Exp2, 
[Forms]![frmCost]![txtYear] as Exp 3, 
[Forms]![frmCost]![txtCost] as Exp 4
```

Comment: Tried using a `DCount` to check if there already was an entry? Please show us your attempt, and how you're triggering the query (macro or VBA).

Comment: My attempt is  based on the msaccess unbounded frontend,  The update query "Update tblCosts set tblCosts.Cost=[Forms]![frmCost]![txtCost] where tblCosts.ExpenseType = [Forms]![frmCost]![txtExpType] and tblCosts.Month = [Forms]![frmCost]![txtMonth] and tblCosts.Year = [Forms]![frmCost]![txtYear]

Comment: And the insert query : Insert into tblCosts (ExpenseType , Month, Year, Cost) Select [Forms]![frmCost]![txtExpType] as Exp1,  [Forms]![frmCost]![txtMonth] as Exp2, [Forms]![frmCost]![txtYear] as Exp 3, [Forms]![frmCost]![txtCost] as Exp 4               Like i said both the update and insert queries run when when i manually run them, its just i need help with the condition when to trigger them  (insert if new record, update if existing record)

Comment: I was hoping there would be a single way either via a query or action to determine this hence tagged both access and sql guys

Comment: But how are you calling the query? Are you manually executing it via the navigation pane, or do you have a button on the form?

Comment: You can replace your two queries with one: [Update and Append Records with One Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29267266/access-compare-two-tables-and-update-or-insert-data-in-first-table/29272782#29272782)

Comment: @Erik i am placing that action on text box txtCost after update event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need code (VBA or macro) behind a form that determines which action query to run. In VBA something like:

```
If DCount("*", "tablename", "ExpenseType='" & Me.cbxExpense & "' AND [Month]='" & Me.tbxMonth & "' AND [Year]=" & Me.tbxYear) = 0 Then
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tablename (Expense, [Month], [Year], Cost) VALUES ('" & Me.cbxExpense & "', '" & Me.tbxMonth & "', " & Me.tbxYear & ", " & Me.tbxCost & ")"
Else
    CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tablename SET Cost=" & Me.tbxCost & " WHERE Expense='" & Me.cbxExpense & "' AND [Month]='" & Me.tbxMonth & ", [Year]=" & Me.tbxYear
End If
```

Probably also want some validation code to make sure all four controls have data before executing queries.

The real trick is figuring out what event to put code into - the Cost AfterUpdate will work as long as the other fields have data entered first, otherwise the validation will fail and user will have to re-enter cost.

Could have code that doesn't make each control available until previous value is entered.

Month and Year are reserved words and should not use reserved words as names for anything.

Would be better to save month numbers instead of month names for sorting purposes.

Why updating a value which really should be a calculated aggregation of transaction records?

Comment: Totally agree with everything here.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks June7