# how to use both update and insert in a same access query

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

I have query to insert but I am unable to update the values with the same query

here is an example

```
userid      date         time          result           sr no

1           11/29/17        11:30 AM   pass              1
2           11/29/17        11:45 AM   pass              2
3           11/29/17        12:00 AM   fail              3
4           11/29/17        12:30 AM   pass              3
```

I have updated the values in the access and so I need to update the value to the oracle. I have used the insert query to insert the values but once it is inserted. I can't update because I used null in my condition.

can anyone give me the solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upserting in MS-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199417/upserting-in-ms-access)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access - compare two tables and update or insert data in first table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29267266/access-compare-two-tables-and-update-or-insert-data-in-first-table)

Answer (score 0):

You did not put any query so I cannot refer to any specific one, but you can just use  INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
Check out this manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html There's samples you can copy.