# Excel VBA Update or Insert into Existing Access Table with Dependencies

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I want to upload all rows from Excel worksheet (`shReceiver`) to an MS Access table (`tblReceiver`).

There is a single primary key - `TNR` (Ticket number) in both Excel as well as the Access table (`tblReceiver`). So first I check if `TNR` from `shReceiver` exists in `tblReceiver`. If so, then I delete the data in `tblReceiver`. Then I append all data from `shReceiver` to `tblReeiver`.

However, a lot of queries in Access DB are associated with `tblReceiver`, which makes this process extremely slow (30 min plus for execution). Is there any way to disable the other Access DB queries or indexes, when updating the `tblReceiver`?

Please note that I have around 70k+ records with 74 columns in `tblReceiver` and 10k+ data for upload in the `shReceiver`.

My code is as follows:

```vb
Public Sub ExportReceiver()
Dim lastRow, var_Range_Count As Long
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Receiver")
lastRow = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

Call databaseCon
For var_Range_Count = 3 To lastRow
    cnn.Execute "DELETE * FROM tblReceiver WHERE tblReceiver.[TNR] =" & "'" 
    & sh.Range("A" & var_Range_Count).Value & "'", dbFailOnError
Next
Call CloseDB

Dim acc As New ACCESS.Application
acc.OpenCurrentDatabase ThisWorkbook.Path & "\TicketsDB.accdb"
acc.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
        TransferType:=acImport, _
        SpreadSheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
        TableName:="tblReceiver", _
        FileName:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName, _
        HasFieldNames:=True, _
        Range:="Receiver$A2:BX" & lastRow

acc.CloseCurrentDatabase
acc.Quit
Set acc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you considered issuing an update query upon finding that the record already exists, and an insert if it does not?

Comment: HI Jard, Thanks for the advice. I didnot use the Update and Insert query as I was trying to append all data in one go. Let me try that one. However, the biggest issue is that as soon as tblReceiver is modified slightly, lot of other queries start processing in excess itself. Is there any way to disable those queries...

Answer (score 1):

Don't import the Excel data but link them as a *linked table*.

Then use that table as source in a combined update/append query as described here:

[Compare two tables and update or insert data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29267266/access-compare-two-tables-and-update-or-insert-data-in-first-table/29272782#29272782)

This will run in one go.

Comment: Thats something, which might help me. Let me implement it. Thanks a lot for this link :)

Comment: Hi @Gustav, I tried the method provided by you, but it is just updating the data. It is not appending any new rows. This is the code after the method used in the link provided by you : `UPDATE tbl_Test_New LEFT JOIN tbl_Test_Old ON tbl_Test_New.PersNum = tbl_Test_Old.PersNum SET tbl_Test_Old.PersNum = [tbl_Test_New].[PersNum], tbl_Test_Old.Name = [tbl_Test_New].[Name], tbl_Test_Old.Surname = [tbl_Test_New].[Surname];`

Comment: Then you either have no new records, or `PersNum` is not unique. You have to join on either one _unique_ field or two or more fields that together uniquely identify the record.

Comment: Well, you see that both tables are test tables with just 5 records and the PersNum is unique and primary key. I think it will do the update but for append: we need to go further with the outer join of both tables and then insert.

Comment: Can't tell. Perhaps something else is going on. I haven't seen a situation where it didn't run as expected.