# How can I configure MS Access(2016) Front End – Linked to PostgreSQL back end

Tags: postgresql, ms-access

I have one scenario with MS Access and PostgreSQL database.

My attendance table stored in MS Access 2016. As the MS Access is limited storage capability, I am looking towards to push the data in to PostgreSQL database.

```
Edit
```

I have installed the ODBC Driver from https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/

What are the steps to do further to connect the data sync from MS Access to PostgreSQL DB?

Answer (score 1):

Install and use the official [psqlODBC - PostgreSQL ODBC driver](https://odbc.postgresql.org/).

Then, in Access, link your table in PostgreSQL. 
Next, write an append query that uses your table in Access as source and appends the records to the table in PostgreSQL.

You may need a [combined append/update query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29267266/access-compare-two-tables-and-update-or-insert-data-in-first-table/29272782#29272782) if you modify data in Access and wish these synced to PostgreSQL.

Comment: I have done that. Then how the data in the MS Access can push to the PostgreSQL database

Comment: See extended answer, please.

Comment: You either work with Linked Tables so its pretty much as the normal Access tables or with Pass-Through Queries (INSERT)