# Check the value exists, if yes update if not insert ms access vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

Good day to all of you

In my database table there are two fields (`mDate`, `mSales`).

If the date exist already then update the sales value; if not exist insert new sales value. I'm using MS Access 2007 and vb.net 2012

When I execute the following `IIF` function it shows an error message.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT mDate FROM MasterDB WHERE mDate='@dateValue') UPDATE MasterDB SET mSales = mSales + @salesValue WHERE mDate ='@dateValue' ELSE INSERT INTO MasterDB (mDate, mSales) VALUES ('@dateValue', @salesValue)
```

The error message:

> Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'.

Please help me if there are any alternative ways or corrections in my `IIF` function.

Comment: You can´t do that in Access. You have to have logic in VB .NET to detect if the datarecord is there and depending on that do an INSERT or UPDATE command. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199417/upserting-in-ms-access). 
Look also for the term Upsert. 
Access neither supports the `Merge` command like SQL Server does.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Alex. I found an alternative way after hard attempts. And, I dont know why (localDB) the mdf file created in inbuilt sql with VS, doesnt support SAP CrystalReport. Or if is there any way to connect SAP CR, please let me know. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should ask that in a new question

Comment: I understand. Thanks Alex

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access - compare two tables and update or insert data in first table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29267266/access-compare-two-tables-and-update-or-insert-data-in-first-table)

Comment: Hi Gustav. I need to update/ insert in the same table. Thanks for your effort.