# SQL left join without deleting data

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table (T_Individus) in Microsoft Access, and I would like to:

- append and update this table from another table (T_importTable)
- without overwriting existing data in T_Individus with empty data from T_imporTable (unlike the upsert solution [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29267266/access-compare-two-tables-and-update-or-insert-data-in-first-table)):

T_Individus

```
dbid    name         Age
------------------------------
100     xyz          5
101     aaa          41
102     bbb          25
103     ccc
```

T_importTable

```
dbid    name         Age
------------------------------
101     aaa          42
102     bbb          
103     ccc          52
104     ddd          27
```

Desired output for T_Individus:

- correction of age for dbid 101
- adding age for dbid 103
- adding row for dbid 104
- no modification for dbid 102

```
dbid    name         Age
------------------------------
100     xyz          5
101     aaa          42
102     bbb          25
103     ccc          52
104     ddd          27
```

Currently I use this code

```
UPDATE T_importTable LEFT JOIN T_Individus ON T_importTable.dbid = T_Individus.dbid 
SET 
T_Individus.name = [T_importTable.name], 
T_Individus.Age = [T_importTable.Age];
```

But with this solution, the age of dbid 102 is deleted (as for the upset solution). Is there another function, or should we use an if condition?

Best,

Comment: Try `T_Individus.Age = Nz([T_importTable.Age], T_Individus.Age)`

Comment: @GordThompson Thank you for this function, I had finally used `IIf(T_importTable.name Is Null, T_Individus.name, T_importTable.name)`, but `Nz()` is simpler.